# Writing table from AWS Glue to MySQL8 (RDS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-rds, aws-glue, mysql-8.0

I have a DynamicFrame with data that I want to upload to a MySQL8 table. I wrote the following code (I have a JDBC MySQL8 driver  a S3 bucket):

```
options = {
'customJdbcDriverS3Path': 's3-jdbc-path', 
'customJdbcDriverClassName': 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver', 
'user': 'user_name',
'password': 'pwd', 
'url': 'url:port/db',
'connectionType': 'mysql',
'dbtable': 'table_name',
'database': 'db'}

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(df, connection_type="mysql", connection_options=options)
```

But when I run the job, it takes indefinitely long time and returns no error message. I've used the same set of options above and the code

```
frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="mysql", connection_options=options)
```

to successfully read from a table on the same database I'm trying to write to now.

Why isn't it working? How can I write to my MySQL8 table on RDS using AWS Glue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it works. It just takes a long time.